# Prevent underscores from removing text?

Tags: 8, forms, search

Drupal seems to be removing all text prior to an underscore in my form. This is in the Form.php file of my module implementing Google CSE, so I cannot change the attribute name.

```
if (array_key_exists('search_broadness', $get_results) && $get_results['search_broadness'] == 'narrow') {
  $block .= 'data-as_sitesearch="' . $gcse_narrow_search_query . '"';
}
$form['search']['results'] = array(
  '#type' => 'item',
  '#markup' => $block,
  '#allowed_tags' => ['script', 'div'],
)
```

And this is the output, note that the data-as_sitesearch is shortened to sitesearch.

```
<div class="gcse-searchresults-only" sitesearch="https://www.example.com/drupal8_gcse/"></div>
```

The Drupal Google CSE module does not have this feature, so I cannot use that. #markup in Drupal 7 worked to get around this, but not in Drupal 8. Is there a workaround to bypass this sanitation?

Comment: What adds those attributes?

Comment: It is a part of the Google Custom Search API, see [Google CSE Elements](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element)

Comment: It's pretty insecure (make sure you don't do this if you have user-submitted input being rendered in the markup), but using an `inline_template` would probably work

Comment: No I mean, what part of the render path inside of Drupal is adding those attributes?

Comment: $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\cse_selector\Form\ResultsForm'); I think this is what you mean, It is in my module's Controller.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm struggling to understand what that code is trying to do; I'm assuming your end goal is to render either this:

```
<div class="gcse-searchresults-only"></div>
```

Or this, if the condition passes:

```
<div class="gcse-searchresults-only" data-as_sitesearch="https://www.example.com/drupal8_gcse/"></div>
```

But I don't see how the code sample would ever to get to even the result in your question. There's no mention of a `<div>`, and if `$block` contains the opening `<div...`, then you've forgotten to close the opening tag and provide a closing tag after concat'ing the attribute string.

To make the whole thing easier (and a bit cleaner), you can use `html_tag` instead:

```
$form['search']['results'] = [
  '#type' => 'html_tag',
  '#tag' => 'div',
  '#attributes' => ['class' => ['gcse-searchresults-only']],
  '#value' => '',
];

if (array_key_exists('search_broadness', $get_results) && $get_results['search_broadness'] == 'narrow') {
  $form['search']['results']['#attributes']['data-as_sitesearch'] = $gcse_narrow_search_query;
}
```

Comment: I isolated only the lines that I was having trouble with, sorry for any confusion, the div tags have other attributes that were unrelated to this question. Thanks for the solution.